# Tabulator: Only return values in 'headerFilter' that are currently in the table

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I was wondering if this issue has happened to anyone else whilst using tabulator.

I'm trying to create a table with the `headerFilter` set to `select`. i.e., inside the column Definitions:
`{title: 'title', headerFilter:'select'...}`.

The issue that I am having is that when setting `{headerFilter:'select', headerFilterParams: {values: true}}` this returns every possible filter option for the column. I'm aware this is probably the intended function of `{values: true}`, but I was wondering whether there is a way of only showing the option to filter on the data currently in the table (i.e., the filtered data).

I looked through the Tabulator documentation, and I cannot find anything related to the problem I'm having.

I did however create my own function to do this for me: which can be found [here](https://codepen.io/lukeorriss/pen/dyZwwez) (Codepen.io). Uncommenting lines 30-32 will activate the function that I have created. There are issues with it. This codepen also showcases the two issues that are being mentioned. Aside being spaghetti code:

1. When using `{frozen:true}` in the column definitions, I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'position')` relating to FrozenColumns.js (line 295) `element.style.position = "absolute";`.
2. When adding values to `headerFilterParams` from the filtered data in the table. I suspect this is an issue with the object keys getting overwritten, instead of merging them together. But before I go down the route of trying to concatenate object with duplicates into one entry, I wanted to make this post.

If anyone could help me with any of these issues / inform me of a much easier and cleaner way to implement this function - it would be GREATLY appreciated. I've spent too many hours on trying to wrap my head around this issue.

Tabulator: v5.1.6.
jQuery: v.3.6.0

Thanks all in advanced :)

Answer (score 1):

For those that have the same issue, I fixed the issue by first: upgrading to Tabulator v5.2, and then changing `{headerFilter: "select", headerFilterParams:{values:true}}` to `{headerFilter: "list", headerFilterParams:{valuesLookup: "active"}}`